Web Audio API: how do I play audio from a DASH stream without audio artifacts?
I am trying to play audio from https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps.mpd using a custom player. The player I have does the following:

Downloads and decodes each segment of audio one at a time using Web
Audio API's AudioDecoder
Stitches all the decoded data from each segment together into a 4 (4-ish since it's actually 192512/48000) second long Float32Array for each channel.
Creates an AudioBufferSource using audioCtx.createBufferSource() and attaches the Float32Arrays buffer to it.
Schedules the AudioBufferSource to play using the timing information. So first segment is scheduled at 0 to play for segment.duration, second segment is scheduled from the previous segment's end time, etc.

When doing this I get about 0.1 seconds of silence between segments. Moreover, the beginning of most (but not all segments) contains roughly 360 samples that are just 0.
When I play the same DASH stream through the dash.js player I don't get the same effect. Is the problem I am seeing with my scheduling algorithm, my decoding strategy, or is there something fancy that other players do to blend the sound together to prevent this artifact?



Schedules the AudioBufferSource to play using the timing information. So first segment is scheduled at 0 to play for segment.duration, second segment is scheduled from the previous segment's end time, etc.


No, that isn't going to work.
You need something that's sample-accurate, which is basically impossible to do when you're measuring time in seconds or milliseconds.  Things won't always be nicely divisible, so even if you get the scheduling extremely accurate, there will always be a small glitch.
You can get around that issue by managing your own buffer and making a ScriptProcessorNode for playback, but that method isn't suitable for your data source... read on...

Moreover, the beginning of most (but not all segments) contains roughly 360 samples that are just 0.

This is a common problem when using lossy codecs.  Sometimes, data from one frame depends on another.  But also, starting a new segment requires some initialization.  The issue is that you're decoding these chunks separately and you shouldn't be.

is there something fancy that other players do to blend the sound together to prevent this artifact?

Yes.  They don't use this method at all.  They use MediaSource Extensions to shove buffers of media data into the browser, and let the browser do all the decoding and buffering and what not.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API

So basically the WebAudioContext and AudioBufferSource are just the wrong API for this? Also I assume that MediaSourceExtensions API is the right thing? Lastly, I don’t really get the choice in how the audio is segmented/fragmented. I assume it is supposed to work somehow despite using the lossy codec and each fragment is supposed to be decodable on its own, no?

Yep, for these segmented media streams like DASH and HLS, Media Source Extensions is the way to go.  For the audio, keep in mind that if you do try to decode each segment on its own, the decoder doesn't know that you expect to put them back together and had no prior data. In practice,  you can play an individual segment but as you've noted you might have some null samples at the beginning.  When you use MSE, the codec just deals with one continuous stream, even if its data is fed to it in chunks. There's a little more info over on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapless_playback

Thanks. I’ll give MSE a try. Interestingly, I do feed every encoded audio chunk into the same decoder. I call flush() on it after that and maybe I shouldn’t be but I thought the point was that this meant the decoder had perfect info on all the prior state. But in either case, I’ll give MSE a go and hopefully that solves all this. Thanks!
